# Android access Listview inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

I want to make a ListView inside a RecyclerView that should display some data in a list form. I currently have a basic Adapter and RecyclerView with no ListView inside of it, so can someone tell me how to modify my code to include a listview inside the RecyclerView?

Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.AdapterViewHolder> {

    public static class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        TextView summary;

        AdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_title);
            summary = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_summary);
        }
    }

    List<Items> items;

    public RVAdapter(List<Items> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_recycler, viewGroup, false);
        AdapterViewHolder pvh = new AdapterViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterViewHolder adapterViewHolder, int i) {
        adapterViewHolder.title.setText(item.get(i).title);
        adapterViewHolder.summary.setText(item.get(i).summary);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return item.size();
    }
}
```

Items:

```
public class Items {
    String title;
    String summary;

    public Items(String title, String summary) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_recycler:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/recycler_list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/recycler_list_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorSub"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How I'm creating the ListView:
        private List item;
        private RecyclerView rv;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        rv = (RecyclerView) ((Activity) MainActivity.context).findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();

        }

    private void initializeData(){
        item = new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(new Items("Title", "Summary"));
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(item);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: you might be better off if you change the external listview into a recyclerview.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I updated the question, can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
ListView parentListView=(ListView)listview.getParent();
```

you can get parent listView by this way

Comment: So would R.id.listview be the inner listview?

Comment: Yes listview is child and parentListView is parent

Comment: I updated my question to include code, how can I convert this code to include another listview in the already present listview?

Comment: Updated again, please take a look at it again